# Subset data between specific months over multiple years

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `issue_date` column in `df` dataframe denoting day level data.

Based on input of year (y) and months (m), lets say 2020, 2019 & 2018 and April & June. I want to subset the data, between April and June for all years (2018,19,20).

```
 issue_date
1 2019-04-15
2 2019-04-15
3 2019-04-16
4 2019-04-16
5 2019-04-18
6 2019-04-23
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Or in base R : `subset(df, as.integer(format(issue_date, "%m")) %in% 4:6)` assuming `issue_date` is already of class Date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like these could help:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df %>% filter(month(ymd(issue_date)) %in% c(4:6))
```